# How to make Thunderbird open links in Firefox in Kubuntu 18.10?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, thunderbird

Due to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/165327 it looks like Thunderbird is not opening links in Firefox on a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

If a email contains a link in Thunderbird based on Kubuntu 18.10 Thunderbird ask to select an application to open http links. Thunderbird does (not yet) show a list of suggested applications. Instead a file open dialog is shown. In Kubuntu 18.10 select /usr/bin/firefox and if you check on the "remember" flag, you will not be asked again.